# C++ Get object type at compile time, e.g., numeric_limits<typeof<a>>::max()?

Tags: c++, types, typeof

Given `int a;`, I know that the following returns the largest value that `a` can hold.

```
numeric_limits<int>::max()
```

However, I'd like to get this same information without knowing that `a` is an `int`. I'd like to do something like this:

```
numeric_limits<typeof<a>>::max()
```

Not with this exact syntax, but is this even possible using ISO C++?

---

**Thanks, all.** Aurélien Vallée's `type_of()` comes closest, but I'd rather not add anything extra to our codebase. Since we already use Boost, Éric Malenfant's reference to Boost.Typeof led me to use

```
numeric_limits<BOOST_TYPEOF(m_focusspeed)>::max()
```

I'd never used it before. Again, thanks for so many well-informed responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

numeric_limits is what is known as a **type trait**. It stores information relative to a type, in an unobtrusive way.

Concerning your question, you can just define a template function that will determine the type of the variable for you.

```
template <typename T>
T valued_max( const T& v )
{
  return numeric_limits<T>::max();
};

template <typename T>
T valued_min( const T& v )
{
  return numeric_limits<T>::min();
};
```

or just create a small type returning structure:

```
template <typename T>
struct TypeOf
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
TypeOf<T> type_of( const T& v )
{
  return TypeOf<T>();
}

int a;
numeric_limits<type_of(a)::type>::max();
```

Comment: Sadly, I don't think that "type_of(a)::type" is legal. If such a simple trick would have worked, Boost.Typeof would have not existed :)

Comment: @Eric You're right. I just checked and type_of(a)::type cannot appear in a constant expression, such as a template parameter :(

@Plong: I found a link to an explanation of how to implement it properly. I checked in boost, and they are using the same trick, see : http://www.peousware.com/implementer-un-typeof-et-un-foreach-en-c/

Answer (score 9):

```
template<typename T>
T get_lim( const T & x)
{
 return numeric_limits<T>::max();
}
```

the good thing is that you can use it without explicitly specifying T:

size_t l = get_lim(34);

Comment: of course, this doesn't give you a compile-time constant. In C++0x this could be a `constexpr` and you could get a compile-time constant.

Comment: `min` and `max` do not return `size_t`. They should return T (this seems obvious).

Comment: Snippet from numeric_limits:

    template <class T> class numeric_limits {
    public:
      static T min() throw();
      static T max() throw();
    };

Comment: @Aurélien Vallée: you are right, but I can return size_t since I wrote the function. Anyway I have this corrected. Thanx. :)

Comment: Slightly more general: 
template<typename T>
std::numeric_limits<T> NumericLimitsOf(const T&){
    return std::numeric_limits<T>();
}

Answer (score 7):

Just FWIW, C++ 0x will also have `decltype`, which is nearly the same as `typeof`. They picked a new name primarily because the semantics are different in one case. The existing implementation of `typeof` (gcc) drops references from types, so `typeof(int &) == int`. The standard requires that `decltype(int &) == int&`. This doesn't matter very often, but they decided to use a different name to prevent any silent changes to existing code.

Answer (score 1):

`numeric_limits<typeof(a)>` works with GCC.  (If you have it in standards-compliant mode, you may need to use `__typeof__` instead.)

Answer (score 1):

[Starting with C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), you can use `decltype()`:

```
numeric_limits<decltype(a)>::max()
```

See also [Difference between decltype and typeof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130774/difference-between-decltype-and-typeof).