# Keyword typeof in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, typeof

### I know:

- `typeof` is a gcc extension and is not part of the C++ standard.

### Questions:

1. Is the word `typeof` deprecated in C++11? in other words, is it allowed to still use it as a gcc extension when using C++11?
2. Is it correct to say that replacing every `typeof` with `decltype` yields the same behaviour of the code?
3. Assume I have `template<typename T> class wrapper`. What is the best way to declare `wrapper_some_field` such that it is equivalent to: `Wrapper<typeof(some_field)> wrapper_some_field`

Comment: How can something that doesn't exist be deprecated?

Comment: I edited to explain what I meant

Comment: For 2. refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130774/difference-between-decltype-and-typeof

Comment: (1) no, yes. (2) no. (3) use `decltype` together with `std::remove...`, depending on what `typeof` produces relative to what `decltype` produces.

Answer (score 12):

> Is the word `typeof` deprecated in C++11? in other words, is it allowed to still use it as a gcc extension when using C++11?

It's not *deprecated*. It never existed as a keyword. gcc [suggests](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) that if you compile with `-std=c++**` that you instead use `__typeof__`.

> Is it correct to say that replacing every `typeof` with `decltype` yields the same behaviour of the code?

No. For example, given:

```
int& foo();
```

`decltype(foo())` is `int&` but `__typeof__(foo())` is `int`.

> Assume I have `template<typename T> class wrapper`.  [...]

You could write `wrapper<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(some_field)>> wrap{some_field}`, but it'd be cleaner to write a construction function template:

```
template <class T> wrapper<T> make_wrapper(T const& val) { return {val}; }
auto wrap = make_wrapper(some_field);
```

Or, with forwarding:

```
template <class T>
wrapper<std::decay_t<T>> make_wrapper(T&& val) {
    return {std::forward<T>(val)};
}
```

Although in C++17 you wouldn't do this at all and would just use class template argument deduction:

```
template <class T> struct wrapper { T t; };
template <class T> wrapper(T) -> wrapper<T>;
auto wrap = wrapper{42}; // wrap is a wrapper<int>
```

And in C++20, you won't even need the deduction guide.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please provide reference to gcc's advice?
And What is this syntax {some_field}. And does the last one work to declare class field?

Comment: That `make_wrapper` wastefully copies sometimes: a `make_X` should perfect forward in my opinion.

Comment: @HannaKhalil Added. It's called list-initialization. And I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont "should perfect forward"  in case of `make_wapper(T &&val)` only.

Comment: @fiorentinoing No, a `make_` function should perfect forward.  If it is `make_wrapper( T const& )` it shouldn't follow the naming convention of C++ std `make_` functions which *do* perfect forward.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I don't get the point about perfect forward an lvalue (const ref), it either copy too or just not work as you expected it to.

Comment: @fiorentinoing The signature of something to be perfect forwarded from `make_wrapper` shouldn't be `T const&`.  It should be `T&&`, which can deduce `T` to be `X const&` or `X` for some type `X`, then inside the body it should be `std::forward<T>(t)`.  Regardless, my comments aren't aimed at you, they are aimed at @Barry, and comments are not a place for a discussion.

Comment: I added a forwarding version of `make_wrapper`.

Comment: @Barry Sorry for the spam Barry; it was a throw away comment from 2 years ago.

Comment: agreed (both saying same thing, thanks for sharing ideas)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont No worries. Just because it's an old answer, doesn't mean it shouldn't be a good answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
#define typeof(...) std::remove_reference_t<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>;
```

However, if you want to create storage for a type `T`, the way to do it in C++11 is to use `std::decay_t`, or in some situations write your own extension that stores C-style arrays into a `std::array`.

```
Wrapper<std::decay_t<T>> wrapper_some_field;
```

if you want to pass `Wrapper` a type suitable for storing inside of it.

`decay` removes references, converts functions to pointers-to-functions, and arrays of T to pointers-to-T, and removes top-level `const` and `volatile` after that.  These are operations similar to what happens when you pass things to a function as part of the "decay-to-pointer/value" operations.

The result is a type "suitable for storage".  As noted, I'd prefer that a `int[4]` decay to a `std::array<int,4>` but you cannot have *everything*.

Comment: `typeof(int)` gives `int`. `decltype(int)` is an error.